# @class for typedef enum?

Tags: objective-c, enums, typedef

In one header file, I have something like:

```
// PasscodeInputViewController.h

typedef enum {
    PasscodeInputModeOn,     // set passcode
    PasscodeInputModeEnter,  // enter passcode
    PasscodeInputModeChange, // change passcode
    PasscodeInputModeOff     // turn off passcode
} PasscodeInputMode;
```

In another header file, I declare a method that takes an argument of type `PasscodeInputMode`:

```
#import "PasscodeInputViewController.h"

- (void)presentPasscodeInputWithMode:(PasscodeInputMode)mode;
```

As you can see, I use `#import "PasscodeInputViewController.h"` as above so that `PasscodeInputMode` is recognized, but is there a `@class` equivalent for `typedef enum`?

Comment: What do you mean? What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: what's the problem with the #import?

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore, well for class names you're supposed to use `@class` in the header file & `#import` in the .m file. I'm wondering if there's something analogous to `@class` for `typedef enum`s.

Comment: Swift adds a wrinkle. An include in a header may generate the error "include of non-modular header inside framework module". The solution is to move the header into the .m and use @class to forward declare anything missing. But for enums, there's apparently no way to do that. Suggestions?

Comment: @ma11hew28, Forward declaring enums: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073674/342794

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn’t an equivalent.

Enumerations in Objective-C are the same as enumerations in C. Since the underlying type of an enumeration is implementation-dependent (e.g., it could be `char` or `int`), the compiler must know the complete declaration of the enumeration.

That said, a type specifier

```
enum nameOfEnum
```

without listing the enumeration members is valid C provided it appears **after** the type it specifies is complete, i.e., `enum nameOfEnum { … }` must appear beforehand in the translation unit.

In summary: There’s no forward declaration of enumerations, only backward references.

Comment: Thanks!. So, then, I should just stick with the `#import`?

Comment: @Matt Yup. There’s nothing else you can do, really.

Comment: @Bavarious I heard that ObjectiveC now takes advantages of C++11 also, so it supports fixed type enum ?

Comment: @Bavarious, new way to forward declare enums: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946489/forward-declare-enum-in-objective-c?s=1|4.0538

Answer (score 5):

@Caleb, @Bavarious:

Most recent way (Jan, 2017) to forward declare the enum (NS_ENUM/NS_OPTION) in objective-c is to use the following:

```
// Forward declaration for XYZCharacterType in other header say XYZCharacter.h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, XYZCharacterType);


// Enum declaration header: "XYZEnumType.h"
#ifndef XYZCharacterType_h
#define XYZCharacterType_h

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, XYZEnumType) {
    XYZCharacterTypeNotSet,
    XYZCharacterTypeAgent,
    XYZCharacterTypeKiller,
};

#endif /* XYZCharacterType_h */`
```

Similar question [Forward-declare enum in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946489/forward-declare-enum-in-objective-c?s=1|4.0538)

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration of classes is necessary to enable two classes to refer to each other. It's not uncommon to have two classes that are defined in terms of each other:

```
@class ClassB;

@interface ClassA : NSObject
{
    ClassB *objectB;
}
@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject
{
    ClassA *objectA;
}
@end
```

There's no way to make that compile without the forward declaration.

The same is not true of enumerations. `enum` just creates a set of named values... you can't include one enumeration in the definition of another. Therefore, there's never a need to forward declare an enumeration.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is a class that has PasscodeInputMode as a property of it.  That way you can be passing around an instantiated object of that class, and can set/get that property, and do other object-like-things with it (assume that's why you'd want to find a "@class equivalent"