# Why @class instead of #import for ViewController in AppDelegate.h?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a basic best-practices question in Objective C. I understand the difference between `@class` and `#import` but I do not understand why the default Apple Xcode templates do this:

AppDelegate.h:

`@class ViewController;`

.m:

`#import "ViewController.h`

When you could instead just put the latter `#import` in the `.h` and leave mention of `ViewController` out of the `.m` altogether, thereby simplifying by 1 line of code.

Of course, saving 1 line of code is not the issue, I'm just curious why it's being done this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line `@class ViewController;` is a forward declaration so the compiler has an idea what the name `ViewController` should mean. The point is to try to do as few `#import`'s in a header file as possible to speed up compiling.

Imagine a file `a.h` which does `#import "b.h"`. Now every file that imports `a.h` automatically also imports `b.h` which increases the amount of work the compiler has to do. By using forward declarations one can often avoid such additional imports and thus avoid the additional work for the compiler.

The bigger the project and the more complex the class hierarchies and dependencies become the more these `#import`s can become an issue. So it's a good idea to develop a habit of using forward declarations where possible.

**Edit:** After the comments, another important use-case surfaced: to resolve cyclic dependencies. For example, if class *A* wants to reference class *B* and vice versa, one has to be defined before the other. But because they need to know the other we have a paradox. It's solved like this:

```
// Tell the compiler: B will be a class type.
@class B;

// Now we can define A, the compiler has enough
// information to know what B means.
@interface A : NSObject {
    B *b;
}
@end

// Since A is now defined, we can define B.
// Cycle is resolved.
@interface B : NSObject {
    A *a;
}
@end
```

Comment: aside from compile time, would actual program performance be affected by either method?

Comment: great and simpler explanation @darkdust

Comment: As dreamlax said, the runtime is not affected by this. This only has an effect when compiling, so that the compiler has a rough idea about what the name (type) should be. In a `.m` file where you want to use instances of that class you need to do the `#import` the compiler gets to know all the details, like method names and other symbols.

Comment: As a test, I replaced the `@class` with the `#import` to see what would happen, and removed the `#import` from the `.m` -- very strangely, I got a compiler error `Expected specifier-qualifier-list before RootViewController` - why would that be?

Comment: Without the specific code I can't tell, but the error means that the compiler doesn't know what `RootViewController` is. So you're missing a forward declaration or import for that type.

Comment: check this out: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14211240/compile%20error.png I restarted Xcode with no change

Comment: Yeah, but what does `RootViewController.h` look like?

Comment: ah, could it be because `RootViewController.h` is in turn importing `AppDelegate.h`? - that proved to be it, thanks.

Comment: See my edited answer: you found the actual use-case why forward declarations were necessary in the first place ;-)

Comment: thanks, all very useful help. my final question along these lines is the relationship between the `.h` and the `.m` - by importing a `.h` aren't you essentially importing its `.m` as well? that is, the compiler sees them in pairs? In which case, having an `#import` in a `.m` should be similar compile time for all those other classes that import the `.h` since each of those is looking for the `.m` implementations, wouldn't they?

Comment: Xcode passes only `.m` files to the compiler, one at a time. A `.m` file then imports all the `.h` files it needs. That is why you can set the *Target Membership* of a `.m` file, but not a `.h` file. The compiler doesn't treat a `.m` and `.h` file as pairs, it doesn't know (and doesn't care) about any relationship between the two. In fact, you could name your `.h` files anyway you like, the extension `.h` is merely a convention.

Answer (score 2):

A forward class declaration:

```
@class ClassName;
```

Is used in header files where no specific property, attribute or method information is required.

This allows `#import` or `#include` of the header file without any of the overhead that comes with `#import`ing ClassName.h.

Answer (score 0):

`#import` is using for a class that is predefined by us or by Apple xcode but @class is we using before we define it (It's forward declaration of class) , in our parent/ or previous class

so it tell the compiler that  there is a class with this name in our project, so that compiler dont put errors for that class name.

Comment: Formatting could be improved significantly.