# How to declare unknown enum in header?

Tags: objective-c, declaration

I know you can use the `@class` word to declare an unknown class in an objective-c header file. Is there a way to declare an unknown `enum` inside a header class?

For instance, is there a way to prevent the compile error for `someEnum`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class UnknownClass;

@interface Foo

@property (nonatomic, strong) UnknownClass *someObject;
@property (nonatomic) UnknownEnum someEnum;

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you want to import the file that contains UnknownEnum?

Comment: I could of course, but I'm trying to keep the header file as clean as possible. If I don't need to import for class definitions, I'm hoping I don't need to for new data_types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward-declare enum in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946489/forward-declare-enum-in-objective-c)

Comment: Cheers. I'd tried to search for the answer, but didn't realise I could use "forward-declare" keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can *forward declare* an `enum`:

```
enum things;
```

However I think you will run into issues if you start using compiler flags like `-pedantic` as I don't believe it's part of the ISO standard.  I also think, like forward declaring a class, you can probably only use a pointer to it, as its size isn't known.

I've never, personally, ever had to do this and prefer to include the header file defining the `enum` (and I don't think *forward declaring* the `enum` is cleaner than including the file anyway).

Bottom line: **Don't bother**.

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason you do not want to add the `#import` or `#include` directive for the header that *does* declare the `enum`, then just type it as something else. All `enum` types are pretty limited to some form of `int`. Just declare it as similar. If you know you will get 0 or higher you could use `NSUinteger`. If you know you will get negative numbers, use `NSInteger`.
Either of those should be sufficient for your property declaration.

That is to say, named enums are nothing more than typdefs as far as using the value of an enum member or assigning that value to a variable.

Another option is to do `#ifndef` to define the self same type def.

Comment: This means you lose any compiler checking of values assigned to the property.

Comment: Hence, "if for some reason"