# Using Swift `enum` as a property type in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums

I have a Swift `enum` defined like this:

```
@objc enum SomeEnum: Int {
  case one, two
}
```

I can use `SomeEnum` in Objetive-C files normally, but when I want to declare a property in header file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) SomeEnum someEnum;
```

Compiler gives error message `Unknown type name 'SomeEnum'`. What's interesting I can create a property in private interface of the class. Also I tried cleaning the build folder, didn't help. File `<module>-Swift.h` is already imported in `.pch` file. Do you know what is the source of the problem?

Comment: Include your error?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Did you import "YourProject-Swift.h"?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Don't you have another error like **_error: failed to import bridging header '.../YourProject-Bridging-Header.h'_** when you find _Unknown type name 'SomeEnum'_?

Comment: Yeah, I have, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Generally, you should not put some dynamically generated header file into .pch . In your case, YourProject-Bridging-Header.h and your Objective-C class's .h file are getting mutually dependent and cannot be imported. The best and most steady solution is defining your enum in the Objective-C side.

Comment: The answer to forward declaring a Swift enum in your Objective-C '.h' file is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42009056/102315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following trick:

ObjcClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjcClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) SomeEnum someEnum;

@end
```

ObjcClass.m

```
#import "<module>-Swift.h" // The order is important here
#import "ObjcClass.h"

@implementation ObjcClass

@end
```

Downsides:

1. You have to include `<module>-Swift.h` before classes using Swift enums.
2. The other issue is if you decide to export the Objective-C class to Swift via Bridging header then you'll have a problem to resolve that enum.

If you can avoid mixing Swift and Objective-C in that way I suggest you do. Instead you can use Swift classes shared with Objective-C and then use forward declarations (i.e `@class X`) in headers.

The other option would be to move enum to Objective-C side as others suggested in comments.

Side note: `<module>-Swift.h` is better be included in implementation files, don't include it in headers ever to avoid any trouble and circular imports.

Comment: The compiler complains that SomeEnum (or your custom swift enum) is not defined. I was looking for tips on how to include swift enums into objc header files.