# Forward-declare ns_options in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, forward-declaration

How to forward declare NS_OPTIONS in Objective-C?

Related SO question for NS_ENUMS: [Forward-declare enum in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946489/9170523)

Unanswered question on Apple Dev Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16305

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, MSSOption) {
    MSSOptionNone       = 0,
    MSSOptionName       = 1 << 0,
    MSSOptionEmail      = 1 << 1,
    MSSOptionTelephone  = 1 << 2
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward-declare enum in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946489/forward-declare-enum-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 5):

Strictly the same as for NS_ENUM, so the answers from [Forward-declare enum in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946489/forward-declare-enum-in-objective-c) are all valid.

To forward declare your **NS_OPTIONS**, you have two solutions:

#### solution 1

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MSSOption);
```

#### solution 2

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, MSSOption);
```

Both solutions work fine. Tested with Xcode 9.3.1 and Xcode 10.1.
Demonstration at https://github.com/Coeur/StackOverflow50499172.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  For solution 1 I get "Redefinition with different type" and for solution 2 I get "The declaration does not declare anything".  This is with Xcode 10.1. Maybe things changed since you tried it?

Comment: @Baxissimo it works perfectly with Xcode 10.1 too. Demonstration at https://github.com/Coeur/StackOverflow50499172. You're probably just doing something else wrong.

Comment: Yeh, your sample does seem to work fine. Not sure what the difference is.  I tried to change the setup in your code to be more like in our app, but all such mods worked fine.  Maybe I had one as NSInteger and the other as NSUInteger.  That would explain the "different type" error I got.  Though I thought I triple checked that the type for both declarations was the same. 
 Unfortunately I've lost the place in our app I was trying to do this.  It was in the middle of a bunch of refactoring that I hit upon it.

Comment: @Baxissimo were you able to spot the difference? I have same problem, that NS_OPTIONS gave me "declaration doesn't declare anything" and NS_ENUM - redefinition error.

Comment: @CrazySage could it be that the name is already taken? Try to change your typedef to a different name. If that doesn't solve it, maybe check that you're using `#import` on your headers and not `#include`?