# Can an enum be defined in the same file as a class header that uses it in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums, header-files

If not, and it needs to be included in a separate file (e.g. MyEnums.h) do I need to #import MyEnums.h every time a .m or .h file wants to refer to the type or one of the values?

---

Here's sample code of MyClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// #1 placeholder

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}

// #2 placeholder

- (void)sampleMethod:(MyEnum)useOfEnum;

// #3 placeholder

@end
```

Here's the enum I'm trying to define:

```
typedef enum MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

If I try placing my enum definition in #1, I get **error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'**.

If I try placing my enum definition in #2, I get **error: expected identifier or '(' before 'end'**.

If I try placing my enum definition in #3, I get **error: expected ')' before 'MyEnum'**. Which is complaining about the parameter "useOfEnum" because it's type is not defined yet.

---

So can this be done? Or what is the best way to do this and limit the amount of #imports required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work in position #1, but I think you need to write it like so:

```
typedef enum {
    Value1,
    Value2
} MyEnum;
```

To work properly.

**update:** I have confirmed this (at least in Xcode 3.2). The syntax shown above compiles without errors.

Comment: It will also work in position 2 — or anywhere else before the enum is actually used — but it's visually more awkward anywhere but position 1.

Comment: @Chuck: Good point. I didn't even think to check if it would work in positions #2 and #3. Position #1 is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/typedef-enum-in-objective-c/707572#707572 explains why you need to place it after the braces.

Comment: @eagle: Nice find on that link. You can always count on Mr. Rosenfield to provide a quality answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are simply missing the ; off the end of the typedef enum declaration.