# enum explanation needed

Tags: objective-c

I have some doubt in enum in objectiveC understanding

```
enum
{
    kTagWord ,
    kTagSprite ,
    kTagSpriteManager ,
    kTagSpriteError ,

};
```

let's say i have this enum, what does it mean? i really appreciate any helps

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

It defines an un-named enum type with the specified values, which basically just means you are defining a series of constants.

By default, the first value of an enum will be 0 (so kTagWord is 0 in your case) then 1, 2, etc.