# Can an objective C method signature specify an enum type?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an objective C method signature specify an enum type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723138/can-an-objective-c-method-signature-specify-an-enum-type)

"VoiceName" is an enum, declared like this:

```
enum VoiceName {
    PAD_RHYTHM,
    PAD_RHYTHM2,
    PAD_RHYTHM3,
    PEEPERS,
    ATMOSPHERE,
    IMPULSE,
    FAST_PULSE,
    HAIRYBALLS_PADS,
    KICK
};
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like me using it in a method signature like this:

```
-(void)pulseFiredWithSamplePosition:(float)position from: (VoiceName) voiceName;
```

It tells me *expected ')' before 'VoiceName'*. What's going on here?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Comment: I'm going to flag this because it is pretty hard to double post the same question accidentally, so figure someone adminish might want to see if it was simple error or deep SO mystery

Comment: @quixoto: I kept following the links thinking this guy has posted 100 duplicates. Time for more coffee.

Answer (score 5):

You have to refer to it as `enum VoiceName`:

```
-(void)pulseFiredWithSamplePosition:(float)position from: (enum VoiceName) voiceName;
```

Or you can typedef it:

```
typedef enum {
    /* ... */
} VoiceName;
```

Then you can refer to it as `VoiceName`.

Comment: We are cross answering the same question with what seems to be an identical answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember this is Objective-*C*, it needs to be from: (enum VoiceName) voiceName.

If you don't want to say `enum` you can use a typedef.