# Can an objective C method signature specify an enum type?

Tags: objective-c

"VoiceName" is an enum, declared like this:

```
enum VoiceName {
 PAD_RHYTHM,
 PAD_RHYTHM2,
 PAD_RHYTHM3,
 PEEPERS,
 ATMOSPHERE,
 IMPULSE,
 FAST_PULSE,
 HAIRYBALLS_PADS,
 KICK
};
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like me using it in a method signature like this:

```
-(void)pulseFiredWithSamplePosition:(float)position from: (VoiceName) voiceName;
```

It tells me *expected ')' before 'VoiceName'*. What's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an objective C method signature specify an enum type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723136/can-an-objective-c-method-signature-specify-an-enum-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use it "bare" like that without also specifying that it's an enum:

```
-(void)pulseFiredWithSamplePosition:(float)position from: (enum VoiceName) voiceName;
```

should work. If you want to avoid specifying it like that, you can typedef it:

```
typedef enum _VoiceName {
    PAD_RHYTHM,
    ....
} VoiceName;
```

then you'll be able to use just `VoiceName` as the argument type.

Comment: I use the shorter form: `enum { … } typedef VoiceName;`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS6 and Mac OSX 10.8 you can use the NS_ENUM macro

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VoiceName)
{
 PAD_RHYTHM,
 PAD_RHYTHM2,
 PAD_RHYTHM3,
 PEEPERS,
 ATMOSPHERE,
 IMPULSE,
 FAST_PULSE,
 HAIRYBALLS_PADS,
 KICK
};
```

NSUInteger can be replaced with whatever type your defining, then you could use your method as specified.

Answer (score 1):

Obj-C is based on C, not C++. C requires the enum keyword, as quixoto showed. C++ lets you omit it.