# iOS - Is this a task for enums?

Tags: ios, enums, initialization

If I want to implement the following code, would enums be appropriate? I've looked up a few questions on enums, but I'm still a bit unsure.

```
if (dayOfWeek == Monday)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (dayOfWeek == Tuesday || dayOfWeek == Wednesday)
{
    // Do something else
}
```

If this seems right, how would I go about initialising the enum? Would it go in the header or implementation file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I want to implement the following code, would enums be appropriate?

Without getting too detailed about alternatives -- Yes.

> how would I go about initialising the enum?

I typically declare an enum in C like so:

```
typedef enum MONDayOfWeek {
  MONDayOfWeek_Undefined = 0,
  MONDayOfWeek_Monday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Tuesday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Wednesday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Thursday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Friday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Saturday,
  MONDayOfWeek_Sunday
} MONDayOfWeek;

// in use:
MONDayOfWeek day = MONDayOfWeek_Monday;
```

`MON` would be your library or organization's prefix. `DayOfWeek` would be the enum name within the library, then the values are appended.

Although it's wordy, you tend to avoid collisions quite well.

> Would it go in the header or implementation file?

In the header, if you want it to be used by multiple files, else in the implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this would be great for enums, check out this SO post to see the construction of an enum:

[What is a typedef enum in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c)

```
typedef enum {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
} DayOfTheWeek;
```

Also, you can decide whether or not to place the enum implementation in the class you are working in or a header file.