# What is the type of a enum in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums

I'm just trying to figure out if the values themselves are int, unsigned int, NSInteger.  I thought I saw someone say that they were unsigned ints, but in Apple's header files I've seen them used to store negative values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An enum is a feature of C (and C++), not Objective-C.  When you declare an enum you declare a new C data type.

The size of a given enum data type may be the size of a `int`, or it may only be just large enough to hold each of the declared enum values.  It's compiler specific, and there are usually compiler settings to control how enums are handled.

The largest an enum can be is `int`, so you can always convert any enum value to an `int`.  The reverse is not true; you cannot necessarily convert any `int` to an enum value.

Comment: It's a bit more subtle than this. The enum type itself is the compiler-dependent integral type that may be smaller than `int`. But the enum *values* are actually just integral constants.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerated integers are 32-bit `signed int`s at the largest.

Answer (score 0):

It's an enumerated type. You can define your own type that can take on certain specified values.

See this question:
[What is a typedef enum in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c)

So if you had an enum like:

```
typedef enum {    
   NBType1,
   NBType2,
   NBType2,
} NBType
```

the parameter passed to a method would be of type `NBType`.

Comment: But what is the range of values that an enumeration can have.  Also, if a method was being passed a value from an enumeration but did not know it, what would the type of the parameter be.

Comment: It would be the type of what ever you define the enum to be.