# Adding a decimal point button to an iOS Calculator

Tags: objective-c, ios

I followed a tutorial to make an iOS Calculator, and I am now wanting to add a decimal place button to it. Here is my code

header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalcViewController : UIViewController {

float result;
float selectedNumber;

int selectedOperation;

IBOutlet UILabel *calcScreen;
}

-(IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearNumber:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clearOperation:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is my implementation file

```
#import "CalcViewController.h"

@implementation CalcViewController

-(IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender {
selectedNumber = selectedNumber * 10 + (float) [sender tag];
calcScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2g", selectedNumber];
}

-(IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {
if (selectedOperation == 0) {
    result = selectedNumber;

} else {
    switch (selectedOperation) {
        case 1:
            result = result + selectedNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - selectedNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * selectedNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = result / selectedNumber;
            break;
        case 5:
            selectedOperation = 0;
            break;



    }
}
selectedNumber = 0; 
calcScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2g", result];
if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
selectedOperation = [sender tag];

} 


-(IBAction)clearNumber:(id)sender {
selectedNumber = 0;
calcScreen.text = @"0";
}

-(IBAction)clearOperation:(id)sender {
selectedNumber = 0;
calcScreen.text = @"0";
selectedOperation = 0;
}
```

I saw on another thread that someone had suggesting using the method:

```
- (IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender 
{
 NSString *currentText = calcScreen.text;
 if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
    calcScreen.text = [calcScreen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];  
}
```

However this did not seem to work for me. It would indeed let me enter a decimal point, but when a second number was entered the decimal point would be lost. Can anyone suggest a method I could implement to achieve what I am trying to?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: so have u found any solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

My quick thought: keep the number as text on the screen, adding additional digits and/or decimal point to it as text. Only convert it to a float (I would use double myself, btw) at the moment that an operation is performed. The suggested method should then work fine.

Something like:

```
-(IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender {
    calcScreen.text = [calcScreen.text stringByAppendingString:[sender tag]];
}

-(IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {
    selectedNumber = [calcScreen.text floatValue];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could perhaps write up some code demonstrating what you mean?

Comment: Added code example. I have not tested it, so it is probably not entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is creating an error which is causing the app to crash. The line


    calcScreen.text = [calcScreen.text stringByAppendingString:       [sender tag]];

Is sending the error: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int) to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mmmm.... apparently [sender tag] is an integer, while we use it to build up a string. what do you think you may be able to do about that?

Answer (score 0):

One quick tip, instead of using 
`int selectedOperation;...` and later in code

```
switch (selectedOperation) {
    case 1:
        result = result + selectedNumber;
        break;
    case 2:
        result = result - selectedNumber;
    ...
```

Try using `typedef enum`

```
    typedef enum {
    OperationTypeAdd = 0,
    OperationTypeSub,
    ...
    } OperationType
```

and in `switch` block

```
    switch (operationType) {
    case OperationTypeAdd:
        result = result + selectedNumber;
        break;
    case operationTypeSub:
        result = result - selectedNumber;
        break;
```

Comment: Where do I declare the typedef enum?

Comment: You declare the enum type in your header file. In your case it will be `CalcViewController.h` before the `@interface CalcViewController`, and than later instead `int selectedOperation;` you write OperationType selectedOperation. Read something about enum types [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c). I've read you have problem converting integer to string, try using something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intValue];`@George