# Objective-C Enumeration, NS_ENUM & NS_OPTIONS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, enums

What's the correct way to create an enumeration with a specific type in Objective-C? How does NS_ENUM and NS_OPTIONS work? NS_OPTIONS are used for masks, like NSAutoresizing? Thanks.

```
Code from NSObjCRuntime.h
    #define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) enum _name : _type _name; enum _name : _type
    #define NS_OPTIONS(_type, _name) _type _name; enum : _type
```

Comment: The quoted code is defined for C++. The C definition is:#define NS_ENUM(_type, _name) _type _name; enum

Comment: Be sure to check my answer below, the first answer is right, but it didn't give the full difference between NS_OPTIONS and NS_ENUM.

Answer (score 35):

example from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/). NS_OPTIONS is used in a similar way, but for enums which would ordinarily be a bit mask

instead of

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
} UITableViewCellStyle;
```

or

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
};

typedef NSInteger UITableViewCellStyle;
```

do this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) {
    UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
    UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
};
```

an example NS_OPTIONS enum:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIViewAutoresizing) {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```

Comment: But what about NS_OPTIONS?

Comment: like i said, NS_OPTIONS is used in the same way, but it will create bit masked values rather than incremented enum values

Comment: It works even without the typedef NSInteger UITableViewCellStyle, how come you have to add that?

Comment: @mskw you dont need to add that. that line gives you some extra compile time checks, but the point of the examples here was to show NS_ENUM does it in a nicer way

Comment: @wattson12 I don't see how this compile time thing helps, how does it help? What if I named it randomly? Or does it only help if I name it a subset of the enum'ed items?

Comment: @mskw its not the name its the type thats important. by giving an enum a type, you are giving the compiler hints about how to treat an instance of that enum. so if you set it to be an NSUInteger it will be able to perform some basic type checking when the enum values are being used.

Comment: It also means anybody using a method or function you wrote, that takes a bit masked value as an argument, will get compiler enforcement if they try to do something wrong. Say they tried to pass a short int instead of a long int for the bit masked value type. That would be flagged by the compiler. A more likely and bad situation would be the difference between signed and unsigned types. If you typedef with NSUInteger and they supply NSInteger, they could potentially pass a negative value which would be misinterpreted.

Comment: @wattson12 Why NS_OPTIONS has NSUInteger not NSInteger?

Comment: @selva i'm not 100% sure of that, my guess is that because you don't care about sign using an unsigned int gives you one extra option for the mask

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between the two except that they infer different kind of enumerations.

When compiled in Objective-C++ mode, they generate different code:

this is the original code:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyOptionType) {
    MyOptionType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyOptionType2 = 1 << 1,
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyEnumType) {
    MyEnumType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyEnumType2 = 1 << 1,
};
```

this is the code when macros are expanded in `Objective-C` compiling:

```
typedef enum MyOptionType : NSUInteger MyOptionType; enum MyOptionType : NSUInteger {
    MyOptionType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyOptionType2 = 1 << 1,
};

typedef enum MyEnumType : NSUInteger MyEnumType; enum MyEnumType : NSUInteger {
    MyEnumType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyEnumType2 = 1 << 1,
};
```

this is the code when macros are expanded in `Objective-C++` compiling:

```
typedef NSUInteger MyOptionType; enum : NSUInteger {
    MyOptionType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyOptionType2 = 1 << 1,
};

typedef enum MyEnumType : NSUInteger MyEnumType; enum MyEnumType : NSUInteger {
    MyEnumType1 = 1 << 0,
    MyEnumType2 = 1 << 1,
};
```

See the difference of NS_OPTIONS between two modes?

`HERE IS THE REASON`:

There is a new feature in C++ 11, you can declare a type for you enumeration, before that, the type holding enumeration is decided by compiler according to the largest value of enumerations.

So in C++ 11, since you can decide the size of your enumeration by yourself, you could forward declare enums without actually define them, like this:

```
//forward declare MyEnumType
enum MyEnumType: NSInteger

//use myEnumType
enum MyEnumType aVar;

//actually define MyEnumType somewhere else
enum MyEnumType: NSInteger {
    MyEnumType1 = 1 << 1,
    MyEnumType2 = 1 << 2,
}
```

This feature is handy, and Objective-C imports this feature , but it brings a problem, when doing bitwise calculation, like this:

```
enum MyEnumType aVar = MyEnumType1 | MyEnumType2;
```

This code can't compile in C++/Objective-C++ compiling, since aVar is considered of type `NSInteger` but `MyEnumType1 | MyEnumType2` is of type `MyEnumType`, this assignment can't perform without a type cast, **C++ forbids implicit type casting**.

At this time, we need NS_OPTIONS, NS_OPTIONS fall back to enum before C++ 11, so that there is no `MyEnumType` indeed, `MyEnumType` is just another name for `NSInteger`, so that code like

```
enum MyEnumType aVar = MyEnumType1 | MyEnumType2;
```

will compile, since it is assigning `NSInteger` to `NSInteger`.