# what does it mean by type = 1 << 0?

Tags: objective-c, c

everyone. When learning OC recently, I always come across enum like this.

```
enum {
    type1  = 0,
    type2  = 1 << 0,
    type3  = 1 << 1,
};
```

What does it mean by type = 1 << 0 ? What is it usually used for?  Thanks in forward.

Comment: It is left-shift bitwise operator. `1 << 0` is practically equal to 1 but the enum author just want to make it clearer that it is in the same group of latter enums `type3` `type4` etc.

Comment: Really strange and unusual to include 0 though, since you can't treat `type1` as one of the others.

Comment: Assigning values to enum like that is actually a good way to represent flags. For example, you can check the value of the enum variable and determine if it is both type2 and type3 by bitwise ANDing it with (type2 | type3), `(var & (type2 | type3)) == (type2 | type3)` means it is both type2 and type3. Just saying. :)

Comment: Got another tip. So happy! @n3rd4n1

Comment: Read also: [What is the meaning of this declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708493/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-declaration/15708566#15708566)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan So vivid the figure is! Happy!

Comment: @Lilac thanks! I drawn using [ASCIIFLOW](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Poor internet speed that I'm still unable to open the link. I'm sure I'll collect it and try sometime later. It seems so fun.

Comment: @Lilac :) :) yes sure its good tool. I use it for my Q&A

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Another little question: what if I wanna add more types in the enum? type4 = 2 << 1 ? Then it's 4, missing 3. type4 = 3 <<0? Then what's next? A little confusing.

Comment: @Lilac Sorry couldn't understand you Q clearly, but yes you can add two `enum` constants, enums are `int` actually.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I mean if I want to have more than three types in enum, like five, what should I add depending on my original enum without destroying the uniformity? type 4 = ? type5 = ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan God helps me! I happened to see the following codes in UIControl.h.    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlEvents) {
    UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,    
    UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,    
    UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
    UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
    UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
    UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
    UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
    UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
    UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8...
};

Comment: @Lilac yes you got correct!, you can add in same enum definition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitwise Shift Left Operator

> In Objective-C the bitwise left shift operator is represented by the '<<' sequence, followed by the number of bit positions to be shifted

[Source](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions)

Also read [this famous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) to understand what it does and how

Comment: That's really a fantastic post! I just want a drop of water, but you send me a whole spring. I'll read over it and thanks again. :)

Answer (score 7):

<< is binary operator

```
1 << 0 = 1
1 << 1 = 2
1 << 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 5):

It is one bit shift. Such a construction could be used if you need to assign several types to something. It's called bit mask. Example:

```
enum {
    type1  = 1,
    type2  = 1 << 1,
    type3  = 1 << 2,
};
```

Means that type1 is binary 00000001, type2 is 00000010, type3 is 00000100 and so on. So, if type mask is 3 (00000011) you know that your object is type1 and type2.

Answer (score 4):

This operator is a bitwise shift (not only in objective-c).

you can assign every entry in an enum an integervalue, so it is the same as

```
enum {
    type1  = 0,
    type2  = 1,
    type3  = 2
};
```

you can use the shift-operator to easily assure that your enum entries can be bitwise added like

```
int bitmask = type2 | type3 //bitmask = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This offset by zero bits, i.e. his absence.
Just for uniformity.