# Expected identifier or '(' Using typedef enum Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, typedef

Please help! I'm making an iPhone app, and I'm trying to use the 'typedef enum' feature. I heard that this allowed me to easily make my own 'type' so to say. I try to use it, but I get errors, but the code looks correct. Am I using this wrong?

*Code in the .h*

```
typedef enum CoinTypes
{
  Bitcoin,
  Litecoin,
  Dogecoin
} CoinType;
```

*Code in the .m, the lines where the errors are coming from have a '<<' symbol to the right*

```
- (void)checkCoin
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"AboutCoin"] isEqualToString:@"Bitcoins"])
    {
        // Bitcoins was selected
        CoinType = Bitcoin; <<
    }
    else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"AboutCoin"] isEqualToString:@"Litecoins"])
    {
        // Litecoins was selected
        CoinType = Litecoin; <<
    }
    else
    {
        // Dogecoins was selected
        CoinType = Dogecoin; <<
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"AboutCoin"]);
}
```

The error I'm getting is: '*Expected identifier or '('*'

Comment: Apple recommend the use of the `NS_ENUM` macro when defining your type to assist the compiler with type-checking and code completion. See this StackOverflow answer for how to use the macro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962925/what-is-the-diff-between-ns-enum-and-ns-options or NSHipster:http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Comment: Thank you @RoboticCat, I'm now using NS_ENUM. My code is now:            

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CoinType)
{
    Bitcoin=1,
    Litecoin,
    Dogecoin
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CoinType = Litecoin;
```

You're missing a variable name. `CoinType` is the type. Try:

```
CoinType coinType = LiteCoin;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! But I was wondering, how would I achieve putting this in a Global Variable? This method just makes a Local Variable in the `checkCoin` method.

Comment: @CppiLove: Same way you do any other variable: Declare it at the global level (or whatever scope you want).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable of type CoinType:

```
- (void)checkCoin
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    CoinType type;

    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"AboutCoin"] isEqualToString:@"Bitcoins"])
    {
        // Bitcoins was selected
        type = Bitcoin;
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! But I was wondering, how would I achieve putting this in a Global Variable? This method just makes a Local Variable in the checkCoin method.

Comment: same way you'd declare an instance variable or a property of any other type, except the type would be CoinType

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, a variable name needs to be declared.

Additionally consider to use Apples `NS_ENUM` macro:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CoinType) {
    Bitcoin,
    Litecoin,
    Dogecoin
};
```

This macro helps to define the name (here CoinType) and the type (here and usually NSInteger). It hints the compiler for type-checking.

**For further reading:**

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html
- http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Answer (score 0):

typedef is mainly used for creating synonims of existing datatypes.

Basic syntax of `typedef` is:

```
typedef existing_type new_type ;
```

So when you write like:

```
typedef enum CoinTypes {..} CoinType;
```

`CoinType` will represent `enum CoinTypes`.

For fixing this issue,declare your `enum` in any one of the following ways.

**Solution 1:**

```
// Create a global variable
typedef enum CoinTypes
{
  Bitcoin,
  Litecoin,
  Dogecoin
} CoinTypes;

CoinTypes CoinType;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
// Remove typedef
enum CoinTypes
{
  Bitcoin,
  Litecoin,
  Dogecoin
} CoinType;
```