# Difference between enum declarations in C?

Tags: enums, typedef

What is the difference between following 2 enum declarations in C ?

1. `typedef enum colour
   { Red, Blue
   };`
2. `typedef enum colour
   { Red,Blue
   }colour;` //in your response please refer to this colour as colour2 to avoid confusion

Comment: its either enum colour {Red,Blue}; or type 2 in your question
When you use typedef you need to specify the alias of the enumeration. So type 1 is not a valid one.

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand what you mean...can you explain a bit more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c
This will help your for a better understanding of typedef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case, an enumeration can be declared as

```
enum color {Red,Blue};
```

Any references to this must be preceded with the enum keyword. For example:

```
enum color color_variable1;  // declare color_variable of type 'enum color'
enum color color_variable2;
```

In order to avoid having to use the enum keyword everywhere, a typedef can be created:

```
enum color {Red,Blue};
typedef enum color color2;  // declare 'color2' as a typedef for 'enum color'
```

With typedef, The same variablea can be now declared as

```
color2 color_variable3;
color2 color_variable4;
```

FYI, structures in C also follows the similar rules. typedef also makes your code look neater without the C struct(enum) keywords. It can also give logical meanings.

```
typedef int RADIUS;  // for a circle 
typedef int LENGTH;  // for a square maybe though both are int
```

Comment: Thanks! Your link explains it well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the first one is correct at all, you don't need the `typedef`. A named `enum` is enough; example:

```
enum colour {
    Red, Blue
};

void myfunc(enum colour argument) {
    if (argument == Red) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is just the same thing you do when you define a named `struct`.

The second one will define a named `enum` and map a custom type name `colour` to that named `enum`. You could as well make  the `enum` anonymous and only define the custom type name.

Comment: Thanks jmc. This link really explains it well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Actually the simplest example doesn't even need to be named

```
enum{
    Red, //Implicitly 0
    Blue //Implicitly 1
};
```

is perfectly acceptable.

Doing this is only for replacing a bunch of #define statements. You don't want to pass an enum shape value where an enum color was expected.

But you can technically use it in the place of an integer, so

```
int foo(int x){
    return x;}

int y = foo(Red);
```

Will return 0