# typedef in C difference?

Tags: c, typedef

What is the difference between the following in C language:

```
typedef enum month_t
{
jan,
feb,
march
}month;
```

AND

```
typedef enum
{
monday,
tuesday,
wednesday
}day;
```

Before posting this question I read this : [What is a typedef enum in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c)

But did not understand quite well...

Comment: One defines months, the other days.

Comment: In the first case, you could have left off the `month_t` and then the two would be the same way of doing it. The `month_t` is just another type tag in C one can use, so you could declare a month as `enum month_t my_month;` or just `month my_month;`. For day, you can only do `day my_day;` the way it's currently defined.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That is not actually a difference in the C language; there is an isomorphism between them. It is only a difference outside the C language, to its users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first also introduces an enum tag, which means the enumeration can be used like this:

```
enum month_t first = jan;
/* or */
month second = feb;
```

the second doesn't, so the enumeration is only available with the `typedef`:ed name `day`.

Also, of course, the enumerations themselves are different, but that's kind of obvious.

Comment: Yes (upvoted). Putting it another way, the first declares an enum called 'month_t' and typedefs an alias called 'month'. The second declares an anonymous enum and types an alias called 'day'.