# error when initializing enum value

Tags: objective-c, enums

Below is the enum I created in the header file of my Ball class:

```
typedef enum   {
redBall = 0,
blueBall = 1,
greenBall = 2

}ballTypes;
```

and in the interface:

```
ballTypes ballType;
```

in the init method of Ball.mm I initialized ballType as follows:

```
ballType = 0;
```

I get the following error:

```
Assigning to 'ballTypes' from incompatible type 'int'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: @voromax it can be related, maybe even duplicated, but not an exact duplicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums should be defined with the `NS_ENUM` macro:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BallType) {
    BallTypeNone  = 0,
    BallTypeRed   = 1,
    BallTypeBlue  = 2,
    BallTypeGreen = 3
};

BallType ballType;

ballType = BallTypeNone;
```

Typically the name starts with a capital letter and each value is the name with a meaningful description appended to it.

Comment: Even if it solves the problem and introduce a good practice (thanks btw, I didn't know about NS_ENUM), the _real_ problem of the question is better adressed by trojanfoe's answer imho.

Answer (score 1):

`BallTypes` is a type and `int` (literal `0`) is a type and they cannot be mixed without casting.

Create an *invalid* ball type and use that:

```
typedef enum   {
    noBall,
    redBall,
    blueBall,
    greenBall
} ballTypes;

...

ballType = noBall;
```

Note: *Conventionally* enums are capitialized...