# Wrong value from NSNumber to enum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, nsnotification

I'm sending a notification with enum inside:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationTitle object:nil userInfo:@{[NSNumber numberWithInt:option2]:kNotificationName}];
```

And receiving it:

```
- (void)myAction:(NSNotification *)notification {
MyState myState = (MyState)[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:kNotificationName] integerValue];
```

The problem is that myState has wrong value. When i print notification i get:

```
Printing description of notification:
NSConcreteNotification 0x123456 {name = notificationTitle; userInfo = {2 = notificationName;}}
```

But myState == option0.

Why it's happening like this?

EDIT:

```
typedef enum myStates {
  option0,
  option1,
  option2,
  option3
} MyState;
```

Comment: You've got your key and value backwards

Comment: hope this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c/17161563#17161563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you got the value and key switched around.

The dictionary should be used like this: `@{key:value}`

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationTitle object:nil userInfo:@{kNotificationName:[NSNumber numberWithInt:option2]}];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to write your enum function like this:-

```
typedef enum myStates {
  option0 = 0,
  option1,
  option2,
  option3
} MyState;
```

and print both as individual like what output your notification has and what output your myState object has.

Comment: Yea right :) Overlooked that 0. Thanks, will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Vive : great :) i'm glad that it helped you to overcome your issue.

Comment: Well it didn't. That was a bug indeed, but still i have the same problem and getting option0 as result :/

Comment: Even better: use NS_ENUM ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use NSNotification (as you've found out, no compile time check, and really cumbersome to use in many cases like this). Instead, a better alternative maybe to use an event bus like [Tolo](http://genzeb.github.io/tolo) -- very easy to use and automatic removing of subscribers on dealloc. You would just write:

```
@interface EventStateChanged : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) MyState state;
@end

SUBSCRIBE(EventStateChanged)
{
MyState state = event.state;
    // Do something with state.
}
```

Check it out.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this. Will copy it somewhere and try to use later. Thanks for snippet.

Answer (score 0):

User Info is a key => value dictionary:

```
userInfo:@{[NSNumber numberWithInt:option2]:kNotificationName}];
```

Here you have value => key. Try this:

```
@{kNotificationName:@{option2}]
```