# warning on typedef enum when converting app to 64-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, 64-bit

I am converting my iOS app to 64-bit. I have the latest Xcode 5.1 (beta 4) installed.

When I compiled the app, I received over 100 warnings and most of them are pretty easy to fix. However, I have a warning on the following code:

```
+ (CommentResponseStatus)commentReponseStatusCodeWithStatusString:(NSString *)_status
{
    NSArray *commentStatusString = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"success", @"needConfirmation", @"stopped", nil];

    return [commentStatusString indexOfObject:_status];
}
```

Where `CommentResponseStatus` is declared as:

```
typedef enum {
    success,
    needConfirmation,
    stopped
} CommentResponseStatus;
```

I have a warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: '`NSUInteger`' (aka '`unsigned long`') to '`CommentResponseStatus`'"

The warning is on the line `return [commentStatusString indexOfObject:_status];`

In `NSArray` we have `- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject;`

I am confused about this warning and don't know for now how to fix it. Any quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1) about 64-bit changes.

> Enumerations Are Also Typed : In the LLVM compiler, enumerated types can
>   define the size of the enumeration. This means that some enumerated
>   types may also have a size that is larger than you expect. The
>   solution, as in all the other cases, is to make no assumptions about a
>   data type’s size. Instead, assign any enumerated values to a variable
>   with the proper data type

To solve this, **create enumeration with type** as below syntax.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CommentResponseStatus) {
    success,
    needConfirmation,
    stopped
};
```

or

```
typedef enum CommentResponseStatus : NSUInteger {
    success,
    needConfirmation,
    stopped
} CommentResponseStatus;
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd solution and the warning disappeared. I'm not sure about the 1st one though. I did some more searching and found similar answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Comment: I personally recommend the first one because it only has one place to refactor a name change. The latter has two and I also dislike the suffix naming style versus the prefix of the latter.