# How to declare a typedef enum of structs in Objective-C if possible

Tags: objective-c, c

In order to be able to limit the positions to a list of available positions I tried the following declaration:

```
typedef enum
{
    feedbackPositionMiddle = {20.f,80.f},
    feedBackPositionTop    = {20.f,40.f},
    feedBackPositionBottom = {20.f,120.f}

} feedBackPosition;
```

However this code does not seems to be accepted. Does it misses something or is it just impossible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c

Comment: good news is you can do it in Swift. bad news is you can't do it in ObjC/C++

Comment: @BryanChen, afaik in swift you can provide raw values for enum only as literals, so creating 'enum MyPoint : CGPoint' is not possible in swift either

Comment: ha… who will dig the doc to be right :) from what I read if I remember well enum can be of anything even class and.. no it was switch that can be done on anything

Comment: @Vladimir Yes only as literals. However, it is possible to write extension to convert literals to CGPoint

Comment: @Vladimir check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161108/how-to-create-enum-with-raw-type-of-cgpoint/24161109#24161109

Comment: @BryanChen, something like https://gist.github.com/vlk/3d74933d58f590f9bde2, or can it be done in a nicer way?

Comment: @BryanChen, I see now, its really nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare enum only of integral type, so struct or any other composite type is not allowed here. In your case const CGPoint is probably the best option:

```
const CGPoint kFeedbackPositionMiddle = {20.f,80.f};
...
```

Comment: Indeed my question was more something like can we create enum of something else than integral type. thanks, I wanted to avoid the const...