# How to create enum with raw type of CGPoint?

Tags: swift

Inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160175/how-to-declare-a-typedef-enum-of-structs-in-objective-c-if-possible?noredirect=1#comment37286773_24160175). Swift support to create enum with any raw type, so it will be nice to able to create enum with raw type of CGPoint.

But this code won't compile

```
enum MyEnum : CGPoint {
    case Zero
}
```

with following error

```
<REPL>:50:15: error: raw type 'CGPoint' is not convertible from any literal
enum MyEnum : CGPoint {
              ^
<REPL>:51:10: error: enum cases require explicit raw values when the raw type is not integer literal convertible
    case Zero
     ^
```

So how to declare enum with raw type of CGPoint?

Answer (score 36):

There are two errors in given code.

First one is

```
error: raw type 'CGPoint' is not convertible from any literal
    enum MyEnum : CGPoint {
```

So we need to make CGPoint convertible from literal

One way to solve it is to extend CGPoint to make it convertible from String literal by conform `StringLiteralConvertible`

```
extension CGPoint : StringLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromStringLiteral(value: String) -> CGPoint {
        return NSPointFromString(value) // CGPointFromString on iOS
    }

    static func convertFromExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral(value: String) -> CGPoint {
        return NSPointFromString(value) // CGPointFromString on iOS
    }
}
```

we can create CGPoint from string literal now!

```
var p : CGPoint = "2,3"
println(p) // print (2.0,3.0)
```

The second error is

```
error: enum cases require explicit raw values when the raw type is not integer literal convertible
        case Zero
         ^
```

which is easy to fix now, just assign some string literal to it

```
enum MyEnum : CGPoint {
    case Zero = "0, 0"
    case One = "1, 1"
    case MagicPoint = "0, 42"
}

println(MyEnum.Zero.toRaw()) // (0.0,0.0)
println(MyEnum.One.toRaw()) // (1.0,1.0)
println(MyEnum.MagicPoint.toRaw()) // (0.0,42.0)
```

and now you have enum with CGPoint raw type

---

to use it

```
if let p = MyEnum.fromRaw(CGPoint(x:0, y:42)) {
    switch (p) {
    case .Zero:
        println("p is (0, 0)")
        break
    case .One:
        println("p is (1, 1)")
        break
    case .MagicPoint:
        println("p is magic point")
        break
    }
}

// print "p is magic point"
```

---

It will be nicer to create CGPoint from tuple, however, looks like it is not possible.

From the [grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/literal)

```
literal → integer-literal­  floating-point-literal­  string-literal­
```

there are only three types of literal, so string-literal is the only option here (unless you want `1.2` to be `(1, 2)`)

Comment: It will be nicer to create from tuple like `case Zero = (0,0)` but I can't figure out how to do it yet.

Comment: Will it work automatically with `switch` too or will you have to override the pattern matching operator?

Comment: I think this no longer compiles on Swift 2.x+

Answer (score 14):

You can actually have a proper way. This is the code that allows you to have `CGPoint` as a `RawValue` of `enum`:

```
enum MyPointEnum {
    case zero
}

extension MyPointEnum: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = CGPoint

    init?(rawValue: CGPoint) {
        if rawValue == CGPoint.zero {
            self = .zero
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    var rawValue: CGPoint {
        switch self {
        case .zero:
            return CGPoint.zero
        }
    }
}

print(MyPointEnum.zero.rawValue) //prints "(0.0, 0.0)\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

I really like Bryan Chen's solution but I came with one alternative. It doesn't really uses enums:

```
extension CGPoint : RawRepresentable, Equatable {
    typealias RawType = (CGFloat, CGFloat)

    static let Zero = CGPointZero
    static let One = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    static let MagicPoint = CGPoint(x: 42.0, y: 0.0)

    static func fromRaw(raw: RawType) -> CGPoint? {
        return CGPoint(x: raw.0, y: raw.1)
    }

    func toRaw() -> RawType {
        return (x, y)
    }
}
```

Now we can do all that "raw" operations:

```
var p = CGPoint.fromRaw((10, 20)) //from tuple
```

We can also use a `switch`:

```
switch (p) {
case CGPoint.Zero:
    println("p is (0, 0)")
case CGPoint.One:
    println("p is (1, 1)")
case CGPoint.MagicPoint:
    println("p is (42, 0)")
case CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10):
    println("p is (0, 10)")
default:
    println("Something else")
}
```

However, you need the `default` case and you cannot use the short `.Zero` names.