# Storing different types of value in Array in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift Programming Language, it says "An array stores multiple values of the same type in an ordered list."  But I have found that you can store multiple types of values in the array.  Is the description incorrect?

e.g.

```
var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From REPL

```
 xcrun swift
  1> import Foundation
  2> var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
test: __NSArrayI = @"5 objects" {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = "b"
  [2] =
  [3] = "hi"
  [4] = (long)1
}
  3>
```

you can see `test` is `NSArray`, which is kind of `AnyObject[]` or `NSObject[]`

What happening is that `Foundation` provides the ability to convert number and boolean into `NSNumber`. Compiler will perform the conversion whenever required to make code compile.

So they now have common type of `NSObject` and therefore inferred as `NSArray`

---

Your code doesn't compile in REPL without `import Foundation`.

```
 var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
<REPL>:1:12: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Array' to type 'ArrayLiteralConvertible'
```

---

```
 var test:Array = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
<REPL>:4:18: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'Array' to type 'ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible'
```

---

but you can do this

```
var test : Any[] = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
```

Because they have a common type, which is `Any`.

---

Note: `AnyObject[]` won't work without `import Foundation`.

```
var test:AnyObject[] = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
<REPL>:2:24: error: type 'Bool' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Comment: AnyObject is the type

Comment: Is there a way to verify the inferred type of an array?

Comment: Bryan, I have fixed the code error.  Adding Array does it.

Comment: @Boon easiest way is type it in REPL

Comment: var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1] compiles fine in playground

Comment: REPL has been unstable for me.  Bryan, any idea why without the type compiler can't infer that it's an array?

Comment: @juniperi this means either REPL or playground have a bug... not sure which one is correct

Comment: var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1] compiles fine in Xcode 6 as well.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, REPL works good and provides insight to things.  Looks like if you declare an Array type, it's AnyObject[], if you don't, it's NSArrayI.

Comment: Swift have lots "magic" about type inference. Things can convert to other types automatically without notice (like C++ constructor without `explicit` keyword). you can even [convert string literal to CGPoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24161109/642626)

Comment: Just to note, there is a lot of confusion around `Any` vs. `AnyObject`. From Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html -> under "Type Casting for Any and AnyObject".

Comment: @BryanChen: maybe this Any[] is now [Any]

Comment: Try it on Terminal and PlayGround, prove that we need `var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1] as [Any]`, otherwise the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 9):

To initialize an Array with arbitrary types, just use
`var arbitraryArray = [Any]()`.

Answer (score 2):

`AnyObject` is a type and you can create an array that holds those, which (as the class name implies) means it can hold any type of object. NSArrays aren't type-bound and when you create an array with mixed types, it will generate an `NSArray` instead of an `Array`. I wouldn't rely on this, however, since it could change in the future (AnyObject[] is automatically bridged with NSArray).

You can try this in a playground (note: `dynamicType` returns "(Metatype)" and I wasn't sure how to pull out the actually type so I relied on the compiler error):

```
var x = [ 1, 2, "a" ]
x.dynamicType.description() // -> __NSArrayI

var y = [ 1, 2 ]
y.dynamicType.description() // -> Error: Array<Int>.Type does not have a member named 'description'.

var z: AnyObject[] = [ 1, 2, "a" ]
z.dynamicType.description() // -> Error: Array<AnyObject>.Type does not have a member named 'description'.
```

Comment: Martin, I can't get x.dynamicType.description() to compile in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 you can use :

```
var testArray = ["a",true,3,"b"] as [Any]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can also use a struct in your class:

```
struct Something {
        let a: String
        let b: String?
        let boolValue: Bool
        let value: Int

        init(a: String, b: String? = nil, boolValue: Bool, value: Int) {
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.boolValue = boolValue
            self.value = value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The description is correct, an Array stores multiple values of the same type.  The key is that one value has multiple types.  That is, for example, a `String` has types of `String` and `Any`; an instance of a class `Ellipse : Shape` has types of `Ellipse`, `Shape`, `AnyObject` and `Any`.

```
 14> class Foo {}
 15> class Bar : Foo {}
 16> var ar1 : Array<Any> = [1, "abc", Foo(), Bar()]
ar1: Any[] = size=4 {
  [0] = <read memory from 0x7fa68a4e67b0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  [1] = { ... }
  [2] = {}
  [3] = { ... }
}
 17> ar1[0]
$R5: Int = <read memory from 0x7fa68a51e3c0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
 18> ar1[1]
$R6: String = { ... }
 19> ar1[2]
$R7: Foo = {}
 20> ar1[3]
$R8: Bar = {
  lldb_expr_14.Foo = {}
}
 21> ar1[0] as Int
$R9: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Worked and Tested on Swift 5**

You can explicitly state the data type to any. The Any type represents values of any type.

**Type Casting**

```
var test = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1] as [Any]
```

**Type explicit**

```
var test: [Any] = ["a", "b", true, "hi", 1]
```