# Using Codable to parse nested JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I'm trying to use `Codable` to parse JSON data. But having some problems when it comes down to an object with arrays. I've been trying to follow following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014394/7653367), but i'm getting an error `Type 'Feature' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

The JSON data I want are the latitude and longitude data, but i'm struggling to hard to learn `Codable`. I can also add that I tried to grab the `id` and it worked fine, but when i'm trying to go deeper, it just gives me an error.

Any advice? I do want to use `Codable` and not `JSONSerialization`.

#### My struct (So far)

```
struct Features: Codable {
    var features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Codable {
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case geometry
    }
    

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let geometry = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .geometry)
        var coordinates = try geometry.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .geometry)
        long = try coordinates.decode(Double.self)
        lat = try coordinates.decode(Double.self)
        
    }
}
```

#### JSON RESPONSE

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "totalFeatures":1761,
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"LTFR_P_RORELSEHINDRADE.3179814",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  17.929374,
                  59.387507
               ],
               [  
                  17.929364,
                  59.387493
               ]
            ]
         },
         "geometry_name":"GEOMETRY",
         "properties":{  
            "FID":3179814,
            "FEATURE_OBJECT_ID":2406812,
            "FEATURE_VERSION_ID":1,
            "EXTENT_NO":2,
            "VALID_FROM":"2008-10-09T22:00:00Z",
            "CITATION":"0180 2008-09122",
            "STREET_NAME":"Visbyringen",
            "CITY_DISTRICT":"Rinkeby",
            "PARKING_DISTRICT":"<Område saknas>",
            "ADDRESS":"Visbyringen 4",
            "VF_METER":12,
            "VF_PLATS_TYP":"Reserverad p-plats rörelsehindrad",
            "RDT_URL":"https://rdt.transportstyrelsen.se/rdt/AF06_View.aspx?BeslutsMyndighetKod=0180&BeslutadAr=2008&LopNr=09122"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

#### The interested data

```
"coordinates":[  
   [  
      17.929374,
      59.387507
   ],
   [  
      17.929364,
      59.387493
   ]
]
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: As I mentioned above: `Type 'Feature' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable` @Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error the compiler is giving you is because your object doesn't conform to `Encodable`

If you just need to go JSON -> object and not the other way around then you can use `Decodable` instead of `Codable`.

`Codable` requires conformance to `Encodable` so you would also have to implement `encode(to encoder: Encoder)`

After you fix that then you also need to fix your parsing of the nested containers.

Your inner geometry object has different keys than your outer object so you need a separate `CodingKey` to pass.  You also need to go one level deeper than you currently are to get to your coordinates.

This version should work for the json in your question:

```
struct Features: Decodable {
    var features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Decodable {
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case geometry
    }

    enum GeometryKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coordinates
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let geometry = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: GeometryKeys.self, forKey: .geometry)
        var coordinates = try geometry.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .coordinates)

        var longLat = try coordinates.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
        long = try longLat.decode(Double.self)
        lat = try longLat.decode(Double.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly! Thank you very much! I'll mark it as an answer!

Comment: I got another question about this. By using this code above, i'm getting only the first object of the coordinates array. I tried to make another struct but it all gives me the value of nil

Comment: Look at the answer from @vadian.  It pulls all the coordinates as an array

Comment: Yeah I tried it out, but it didn't seem to work when I had to grab more information like both properties values + coordinates. I'll tried using new structs as vadian said, because the coordinates were in an array in an array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you want only to decode JSON adopt only `Decodable`. If you adopt `Codable` and write a custom initializer you have to write also an encoder method. This is the message of the error.

I recommend to decode the JSON into separate structs. This requires much less code. Write an extension of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` as a wrapper for the coordinates to adopt `Decodable`

```
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D : Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        let lat = try arrayContainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
        let lng = try arrayContainer.decode(CLLocationDegrees.self)
        self.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
    }
}
```

The rest are only a few lines

```
struct Features: Decodable {
    var features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Decodable {
    let geometry : Geometry
}

struct Geometry: Decodable {
    let coordinates : [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
}
```

You get the coordinates with

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Features.self, from: data)
    for feature in result.features {
        print(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Do you have example for using the model as codable where we can use the model for both coredata saving model and json parsing model ? I don't want create custom subclass for code data entity and separate model object. I want to use one (1) model class for both which can subclass both codable and nsmanagedobject or anything. In our old project, we used 2 models. And before converting we use mapper method to convert nsmanageobejct to nsobject (core data fetch) and nsobject to nsmanagedobejct (core data save). I was struggling for such example for somedays :(